# Why doesn't this 950 MHz to 2200 MHz Colpitts VCO circuit work in Multisim?

Tags: oscillator, multisim, vco

I found a 950 MHz to 2200 MHz Colpitts VCO circuit from [this web page](https://www.qsl.net/va3iul/High_Frequency_VCO_Design_and_Schematics/High_Frequency_VCO_Design_and_Schematics.htm).

I tried to design it in Multisim, but doesn't produce any signals. Why?

I used BB130 diodes instead of SMV1232 because Multisim has that varicap diode, but it doesn't produce any signal. Why?

[image: schematic in Multisim]

[image: original schematic]

Comment: Did you add a startup source? No you didn't. I usually inject a current pulse somewhere in the circuit (like a 1 ns pulse of 10 uA in parallel with L3) to get is started. In the real world, oscillators start due to **noise**. In a simulator, there is (usually) no noise so the oscillator doesn't start.

Comment: You may need to run a transient analysis for hundreds of microseconds before the oscillator starts. You might also try repositioning C2 to decouple the collector - I have a feeling that may be a circuit mistake.

Comment: I wonder if the oscillator is not working because it is not really a noise source. So would it be right to use a small signal source to try this? Or touching another simple oscillator circuit

Comment: I will try it because in other circuits decoupler capasitor c2 connecting with one ground together but this circuit have two ground

Comment: You were right Bimpelrekkie. Really, the multisim simulator cannot simulate like the real world. I added a noise source to the circuit and it generated a 600 MHz signal.

Comment: @MuratÖzen if you are copying a schematic, and you see a component oriented like R5 is oriented, please do not copy it exactly ... the ground connection belongs at the bottom of the schematic

Answer (score 1):

Try giving it a step voltage of 0-5 V instead Vcc = 5V. In this way, you simulate the "closing" of the circuits (the stop-run.) It works but there is another problem. The behavior is not the one of common-collector BJT.